# UIButton with background image and title using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I currently face a problem when using UIButton. I have the background image designed by others like this:
[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLu1g.png)
and I need to place the title for the button right after the white vertical bar in the background image. I tried to set left edge for the content but since I used auto layout, the frame will be different with different screen size(3.5", 4.7"...). 
Is there a way to put text in the position related to background I want with auto layout.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would split the left side of the background image from the right side. This way you can have two UIButtons next to each other with horizontal space constraint of 0. The right side of the button will have to be placed inside a UIImageView so you can set the image as a property of the view rather that the button's background. You don't have to do this of course, but I prefer this solution as it is easier to manage across different screen sizes.

Here is a visual representation of what I explained above:
[Separated Views for Single UIButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEFeq.png)

You will then need to route the touch events of both buttons to run the same method or function, just so that both the right side and the left are clickable.

Note: I'm not sure exactly what you had in mind for the highlighting of the button, but this will have to be tested and adapted to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It is a way to solve my problem. But I may want the size of text change accordingly. I guess I need to create a custom uiview